# How do I use APEX_UTIL.PREPARE_URL on a URL that contains backslashes?

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-18.2

I'm trying to use [`APEX_UTIL.PREPARE_URL`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/18.2/aeapi/PREPARE_URL-Function.html) to produce an APEX URL for a page that requires a checksum, and I'm trying to set a page item on the destination page to a value that contains special characters. Assume for this question that the only special characters that I'm passing are commas, though my problem seems to apply to all special characters.

According to [the APEX URL documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/18.2/htmdb/understanding-url-syntax.html#GUID-D5510BFC-AF94-4AAD-8B82-FF780A47601D), an item value that contains a comma needs to be enclosed by backslashes. So when I build my URL, I end up with something like this:

```
f?p=112:50:session::::P50_PAGE_ITEM:\123,abc\:
```

Then I pass this URL through `APEX_UTIL.PREPARE_URL`:

```
APEX_UTIL.PREPARE_URL('f?p=112:50:session::::P50_PAGE_ITEM:\123,abc\:')
```

When I try to follow the link that's returned, I get the following error:

> The checksum computed on the request, clear cache, argument names, and argument values (...) did not match the checksum passed into the show procedure.

If I try passing a value that does not contain commas and I remove the backslashes, the value is passed without a problem.

How can I get a valid checksum for a URL that does contain the backslashes so that I can pass values that contain commas (and other special characters)?

Comment: Are you sure this has to do with the backslash ? I tried the following: create page with item P1_NEW and page access access protection set to "Arguments must have checksum". Create a region with pl/sql dyn contect as source and source:
```
DECLARE
  l_url VARCHAR2(200) := 'f?p=&APP_ID.:1:&APP_SESSION.::NO::P1_NEW:H\ELLO';
BEGIN
  htp.p('<a href="'||apex_util.prepare_url(p_url => l_url)||'">page 1</a>');
END;

```
This generates a link with valid checksum.

Comment: Where are you generating the link (same app, other app, pl/sql session ?), what are your security settings (app/page ?), what is the code you are using to generate the url ? Please provide as much info as possible that could help others diagnose your issue.

Comment: @KoenLostrie You're right; it's not the backslash. I was doing my testing with a Tree region, and it seems to escape special characters (including backslashes) in the link even when "Escape special characters" is set to "No". The URL comes out fine as a label, and it also is okay when output by a PL/SQL region, as your example shows.

Comment: I suggest you use APEX_PAGE.get_url instead - it's much simpler to work with as you only need to provide the parameters needed - https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/19.1/aeapi/GET_URL-Function.html#GUID-19A879A7-DA63-4519-B50F-DF20F652586E (note that you still need the slashes `\\` though)

Comment: @JeffreyKemp I agree, but for the sake of this question, I wanted to make it clear that get_url() was not part of the problem.

Comment: Hi @SteveHart, agreed. On StackOverflow you enter an answer if it answers the actual question, but for general "by the way" style comments (like mine), you can add a comment. The idea is to be helpful to future visitors who have a similar problem. That's why I added it as a comment and not as an answer. I hope that clears that up for you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`APEX_UTIL.PREPARE_URL` should handle backslashes fine. The region that contains the resulting URL may be escaping the special characters, causing the checksum mismatch.

To test the actual output of `APEX_UTIL.PREPARE_URL`, try outputting your URL in a PL/SQL Dynamic region. For example:

```
DECLARE
  l_url VARCHAR2(200) := 'f?p=112:50:session::::P50_PAGE_ITEM:\123,abc\:';
BEGIN
  htp.p('<a href="'||apex_util.prepare_url(l_url)||'">page 52</a>');
END;
```